# combine my method with image resize method

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hey I want to add in the capability to resize images to my file upload but I have no clue how to incorporate it with current code:

**My Code**

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
                    cn.Open();

                    OdbcCommand sc = new OdbcCommand(string.Format("SELECT picturepath FROM Pictures WHERE UserID ='{0}'", theUserId), cn);
                    OdbcDataReader reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(reader[0]))))
                        {

                            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(reader[0])));
                        }  

                    }


                    string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
                    string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filenameDB;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";


                    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Pictures SET picturepath ='" + fileuploadpaths + "' WHERE UserId = '" + theUserId + "'", cn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

                }

            }
    }

}
```

**Image Resize code:**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsValid && this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
    { 
        //Create an ImageElement to wrap up the uploaded image
        Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.ImageElement uploadedImage;
        uploadedImage = Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.ImageElement.FromBinary(this.FileUpload1.FileBytes);

        //Create Resize imaging action to apply on the uploaded image
        //NOTE: You may apply any of the ImageDraw built-in imaging actions
        Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.Resize actResize = new Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.Resize();
        actResize.Width = 150;
        actResize.LockAspectRatio = Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.LockAspectRatio.WidthBased;

        uploadedImage.Actions.Add(actResize);

        //Composite the output image by using ImageDraw class
        Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.ImageDraw imgDraw = new Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.ImageDraw();

        //Add uploaded image
        imgDraw.Elements.Add(uploadedImage);

        //Output image settings...
        //For example: save the image in JPEG format always
        imgDraw.ImageFormat = Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.ImageDrawFormat.Jpeg;
        imgDraw.JpegCompressionLevel = 90;

        //Now, save the output image on disk
        string fileName = @"C:\Temp\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.FileUpload1.FileName) + ".jpg";
        imgDraw.Save(fileName);

    }
}
```

For now I just want it all under the one button:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

From my code.

Comment: also is there a way to use something more generic rather than Neodynamic.WebControls.ImageDraw.dll

Answer (score 0):

Resizing photos in asp.net can be pain to resize with good quality. Refer here for example code how to resize your images from fileupload with good quality: http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/How-To-Resize-Image-In-ASP-NET-With-Good-Quality.aspx